# Invalid opcode on estimateGas 'code': -32000

Tags: truffle, web3.py, ganache

this is my contract :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;



contract CloudProject {        
    uint public nbCandidates = 0;
    uint public nbBureau = 0;
    uint public nPartiPouvoir = 0;
    uint public pvCount;

    struct Pv {
    string[] names;
    uint[] voteCount;
}

struct PvF {
    string[] names;
    uint[] voteCount;
    uint[] percentage;
}

struct Candidate {
    uint bureauCount;
    mapping(uint => Pv) pvs;
    PvF pv_final;
}

mapping(string => Candidate) candidates;    
mapping(uint => Pv) bureaux;
uint[] bureauIndices;
PvF our_result;
PvF elecam_result;
PvF vrai_result;    
mapping(uint=> string) candidateName;    
uint candidateNameCount = 0;
//variables de l'intermédiarité
Pv[] pv_set_resumed;
uint[] occurences;
mapping(uint => mapping(uint => Pv)) bureauMiddle;
string[] substrings;

function init(uint nb_Candidate, uint nb_Bureau, uint n_PartiPouvoir) public {
    nbCandidates = nb_Candidate;
    nbBureau = nb_Bureau;
    nPartiPouvoir = n_PartiPouvoir;                   
}


function addPv(string memory name, uint bureauId, string memory pv_names, uint[] memory pv_counts) public
{
    pvCount++;          
    uint tmp = bureauId - 1;
    string memory cand_name = name;

    if((keccak256(abi.encodePacked(cand_name)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Elecam")) && 
    keccak256(abi.encodePacked(cand_name)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked("PV_Vrai"))) && 
    candidates[cand_name].bureauCount == 0)        
    {           
        candidateName[candidateNameCount] = name;
        candidateNameCount++;                        
    }

    if((keccak256(abi.encodePacked(cand_name)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Elecam")) || 
    keccak256(abi.encodePacked(cand_name)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("PV_Vrai"))) && 
    candidates[cand_name].bureauCount == 1)        
    {           
        candidateName[candidateNameCount] = name;
        candidateNameCount++;                        
    }

    candidates[cand_name].bureauCount++; 

    //extraction of pv_names from the string by spliting
    string[] memory pv_name_array = splitStr(pv_names, ".");        

    // remplissage du PV                    
    for(uint i = 0; i < pv_counts.length; i++) {
        if(candidates[cand_name].bureauCount == 0)
            candidates[cand_name].pvs[tmp].names.push(pv_name_array[i]);
        candidates[cand_name].pvs[tmp].voteCount.push(pv_counts[i]);           
    }        

    //remplissage de pv_final
    for(uint i1 = 0; i1 < pv_counts.length; i1++) {

        if(candidates[cand_name].bureauCount == 0)
        {
            candidates[cand_name].pv_final.names.push(pv_name_array[i1]);
            candidates[cand_name].pv_final.voteCount.push(pv_counts[i1]);
        }
        else                
            candidates[cand_name].pv_final.voteCount[i1] += pv_counts[i1];            
    }

    uint sum = 0;
    uint sum_percent = 0;
    uint sum_last = 0;
    //calcul des pourcentages
    for(uint i2 = 0; i2 < candidates[cand_name].bureauCount; i2++) {             
        sum += candidates[cand_name].pv_final.voteCount[i2];         
    }

    for(uint i3 = 0; i3 < candidates[cand_name].bureauCount; i3++) {             
        candidates[cand_name].pv_final.percentage[i3] = candidates[cand_name].pv_final.voteCount[i3]*100/sum;
        sum_percent += candidates[cand_name].pv_final.voteCount[i3]*100/sum;
    }

    for(uint i4 = 0; i4 < candidates[cand_name].bureauCount-1; i4++) {             
        sum_last += candidates[cand_name].pv_final.percentage[i4];         
    }

    uint id = candidates[cand_name].bureauCount-1;

    candidates[cand_name].pv_final.percentage[id] = sum_percent - sum_last;
}


function splitStr(string memory str, string memory delimiter) private returns (string[] memory){ 

    bytes memory b = bytes(str); //cast the string to bytes to iterate
    bytes memory delm = bytes(delimiter);         
    uint i = 0;
    while(i<b.length)
    {
        if(b[i] == delm[0]) { //check if a not space

            bytes memory s1 = new bytes(i);
            bytes memory s2 = new bytes(b.length-i-1);
            for(uint a = 0; a < i;a++)
            {
                s1[a] = b[a];
            }
            substrings.push(string(s1));
            for(uint a1 = i+1; a1 < b.length; a1++)
            {
                s2[a1] = b[a1];
            }
            i = 0;
            b = s2;

        }
        else if(i == b.length - 1)
        {
            substrings.push(string(b));
            i++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }   

    return substrings;     
}

}
```

I'm using web3 py to make addPv transaction :

```
for s in pv_list:
    print(*s)
    j = i%9 +1
    print(j)
    txnHash= cloudProject.functions.addPv(str(s[0]), int(s[1]), str(s[2]), s[3]).transact({'from' : accounts[j]})
    print(txnHash)
    i = i+1
```

accounts is the web3.eth.accounts...
I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ocr.py", line 235, in <module>
txnHash= cloudProject.functions.addPv(str(s[0]), int(s[1]), str(s[2]), s[3]).transact({'from' : accounts[j]})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1151, in transact
**self.kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 
1454, in transact_with_contract_function
txn_hash = web3.eth.sendTransaction(transact_transaction)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/eth.py", line 263, in sendTransaction
get_buffered_gas_estimate(self.web3, transaction),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist packages/web3/utils/transactions.py", line 84, in get_buffered_gas_estimate
gas_estimate = web3.eth.estimateGas(gas_estimate_transaction)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/eth.py", line 304, in estimateGas [transaction],
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/manager.py", line 112, in request_blocking raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction invalid opcode', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n
```

I don't think the error is about the gas limit (i've changed and the error is the same) Please help me check if there is an error in the code.

Comment: There is not a single occurrence of `estimateGas` in the code that you posted!!!

Comment: estimateGas is in the error message. I'm going to post it

Comment: It is not in the error message either!

Comment: Do not use pragma solidity >4.21 < 6.0. 4 and 5 are not totally compatible, let’s imagine what it will be 5.99.. 

Comment: i wanted to use solidity 5.0 but it seems to be solidity 0.4.24

Comment: Very often “invalid opcode” simply derives by a not complete deployment. Very often if you use higher gas limit, this simply disappears.

Comment: Anh how to fix gas limit.. I'm using truffle

Comment: I don't think the error is about the gas limit (i've changed and the error is the same)
Please help me check if there is an error in the code.

Comment: @KouamJosiane What are the parameters that cause `addPV` to fail? Your function is quite complex to debug I'd suggest to try evaluating step by step to determine the line where it is failing. One possible cause is access out of arroy bounds.

Comment: Thanks. It was out of array bounds exception... I caught it using truffle debug